# Python3 Break from a Loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
x = 10
f1:
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(x):
        print(j)
        if j == 6:
            break f1
```

1.How to break from outer loop in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I DID THIS**

```
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    flag = False
    for j in range(x):
        print(j)
        if j == 6:
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
    print(i)
print('Execution completed')
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen from your code, you do not need 2 loops or break using labels. You can simply do

```
for i in range(10):
  print(i)
  if i == 6:
    break
```

The first time i loop executes, j loop executes. As soon as j reaches 6, i loop has to be exitted. So, what is the point of 2 loops or breaking? Still if you want for similar problems, you can try raising a `StopIteration` exception. Try

```
try:
    x = 10
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(x):
            print(j)
            if j == 6:
                raise StopIteration
except StopIteration:
    print('Execution done')
```

This prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
Execution done
```

Comment: used flags as it looks simple and familiar
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    flag = False
    for j in range(x):
        print(j)
        if j == 6:
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
    print(i)
    print('Execution done')
Thanks :)

Comment: Using flags is also a good way of solving the problem. Glad your issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a return statement if the loops are in the context of a function. like in the example below. Alternatively the raising an exceptionwill effectively stop the outer loop.

```
>>> def doit():
...   for i in range(0,10):
...     for j in range(10,20):
...       print(i,j)
...       if j==12:
...         return
...
>>> doit()
0 10
0 11
0 12
```

Comment: used flag as it looks simple and familiar
x = 10
for i in range(x):
    flag = False
    for j in range(x):
        print(j)
        if j == 6:
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
    print(i)
    print('Execution done')